# Directly point an element from a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP, is it possible to point an element like this if I do not want to use an array ?

```
Array
(
    [France] => Array
        (
            [Paris] => Array
                (
                    [Population] => 8000000
                    [PopulationName] => Parisiens
                ),
            [Toulouse] => Array
                (
                    [Population] => 3000000
                    [PopulationName] => Toulousains
                )
        )
)
```

So for example, if I want to have the population for Toulouse, I can do:

```
echo $array[['France']['Toulouse']['Population']];
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So close: `echo $array['France']['Toulouse']['Population'];`

Comment: @JohnConde, thanks. Is it a bad practice to do so?

Comment: Why would it be a bad practice?

Comment: Due to the -1 about the question I've asked.

Comment: Downvotes can mean lots of things. In this case it definitely not mean it is a bad practice.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: you have an extra `[` `]` in your echo example.

Comment: @tim We already came to that conclusion in the very first comment

Comment: Fair enough to close this under-researched question as off-topic typo.